# CentOS: View all users in a specific group

Tags: linux, centos, user-accounts, centos-6, user-groups

I added a user `user01` to a group `group01` using: `usermod -a -G group01 user01`

When I run in command `id user01` it shows that this user has actually been added to the group.

However, the file `/etc/group` doesn't reflect this.
i.e. I believe that on this file, users that belong to each of the groups should be listed next to it. Please correct me if I am wrong.

This is a fresh installation of CentOS 6.4

Also, since `id user01` shows that this is updated, is there any way to check all the members of group `group01`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run `getent group group01` you should see a list of all members of that group.

Comment: Thanks @John. The command works and I am able to see the users in this group using this. Do you know if `/etc/group/` is supposed to be automatically updated with the list of members? And if so, any reason why it would not update? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updating `/etc/group` is one way of recording new group memberships. I'm not really sure if this is supposed to happen automatically or not. I'd need to know a lot more about your environment before I could really have any idea where to look next.

Comment: I just installed a fresh copy of CentOS and I am only using this to familiarize myself with linux. I just created groups and assigned memberships without directly writing to the `/etc/group` file. Not sure why the file doesn't update when I do so..

Answer (score 1):

/etc/group is a source of group information, but not necessarily the only one.  If your system is set up to use NIS, LDAP, or some other source of user/group information, that information will not necessarily be reflected in /etc/group.

getent reads and reports from all of the configured data sources, of which /etc/group is only one.  I specifically use getent because I use local password/group information in conjunction with a remote LDAP source (configured with PAM modules) and wanted to have consolidated information.

Also, /etc/group is not updated automatically based on external authentication sources.  It is updated directly, either using an editor (such as vi, emacs, etc) or by tools for modifying user/group information (groupadd, useradd, etc).